# Poker game : find likelihood of winning for a player

Tags: java, concurrency, combinatorics, fork-join

I have java based application for Texas Holdem Poker. I have to introduce a feature wherein whenever all players except one goes for all in, we have to calculate probability of winning for each player.

This can happen in pre-flop, flop & turn round. As you may know in pre-flop stage all 5 cards have to be chosen, in flop there are already 3 community cards in the table,  2 more cards have to be
chosen, whereas in turn round 1 more cards have to be chosen. Let us assume there are 2 players.

So each of the players have 2 hole cards. So we have to choose 2 cards from deck of  52 -2*2 = 48 cards. By using combinatorics I am able to do that. But in pre-flop stage there are too many combinations, from 48 we have to choose 5 cards which is 48Cr5 = 1712304 combinations. If I do that much computation the game gets stuck. So tried to use ForkJoinPool. I found there are only 2 cores in the machine where the application is deployed. It is not working at all. Is ForkJoinPool suitable for this task or should I go for some other ExecutorService. Here is some of my RecursiveTask code

```
public class WinnerPercentageTask extends RecursiveTask<List<String>> {
    
    private static int threshold = 50_000;
    
    private List<List<Byte>> combinations;
    
    private int start;
    private int end;
    
    private ITexasHoldemGame game;
    
    
    public WinnerPercentageTask(ITexasHoldemGame game, List<List<Byte>> allCombinations, int start, int end) {
        super();
        this.game = game;
        this.combinations = allCombinations;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> compute() {
        if (end - start < threshold) {
            return computeDirectly();
        }
        else {
            int middle = (end + start) / 2;
            WinnerPercentageTask subTask1 = new WinnerPercentageTask(game,combinations, start, middle);
            WinnerPercentageTask subTask2 = new WinnerPercentageTask(game,combinations, middle, end);
 
            invokeAll(subTask1, subTask2);
 
            List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
            ret.addAll(subTask1.join());
            ret.addAll(subTask1.join());
            return ret;
        }
    }

    private List<String> computeDirectly() {
        List<Card> communityCards = game.getCommunityCardsDealt();
        List<Winner> winners = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> winnersForAllCombinations = new ArrayList<>();
        for(List<Byte> combination: combinations.subList(start, end)) {
            List<Card> allCommunityCard = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Card c : communityCards) {
                allCommunityCard.add(new Card(c.getId(), c.getFaceValue(), c.getSuit()));
            }
            for (Byte b : combination) {
                Card fakeCommunityCard = new Card(b);
                allCommunityCard.add(fakeCommunityCard);
            }
            List<PokerHand> playerRankList = calculateHandRank(allCommunityCard);
            winners = prepareWinnerList(playerRankList);
            winnersForAllCombinations.addAll(
                    winners.stream()
                    .map(Winner:: getPlayerId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
             
        }
        return winnersForAllCombinations;
        
    }
    
    private List<PokerHand> calculateHandRank(List<Card> communityCardsDealt) {

        List<PokerHand> playerRankList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Map<String, List<Card>> playersCards = this.game.getCardsDealtForAllPlayers();
        
        playersCards.forEach((player, holeCards) -> {
            PokerHand pokerHand = new PokerHand(player, holeCards);
            HandRanker.checkRanking(pokerHand, communityCardsDealt);
            playerRankList.add(pokerHand);
        });
        Collections.sort(playerRankList);
//        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
//            logger.info("Player Rank List : {}", playerRankList);
//        }
        
        return playerRankList;
    }
    
     private List<Winner> prepareWinnerList(List<PokerHand> playerRankList) {

            List<Winner> winnerList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(playerRankList)) {

                // Grouping Players based on similar Ranks
                Map<HandRankingEnum, List<PokerHand>> groupByRankMap = playerRankList.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PokerHand::getRankingEnum));

                // Sort the Map based on Rank, highest rank first
                List<Map.Entry<HandRankingEnum, List<PokerHand>>> sortedWinnerList = groupByRankMap
                        .entrySet().stream().sorted(reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                // Reading the Winners of highest rank
                Map.Entry<HandRankingEnum, List<PokerHand>> winnerListMap = sortedWinnerList
                        .get(0);

                List<PokerHand> highestRankList = winnerListMap.getValue();
                List<PokerHand> winnerHandList = new WinnerIdentifier().getWinners(highestRankList);

                for (PokerHand hand : winnerHandList) {
                    Winner winnerPlayer = Winner.builder()
                            .rank((byte) hand.getRankingEnum().getValue())
                            .rankName(hand.getRankingEnum().name())
                            .playerId(hand.getGamePlayerId()).cards(hand.getRankingList())
                            .pots(new ArrayList<>()).build();

                    winnerList.add(winnerPlayer);
                }

            } 
            
            return winnerList;
        }

}
`
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right approach. I'm no a Poker expert but as far as I know good players are calculating the "rough" odds of them winning in their heads (or they have memorized them) and thus I'd say there's a better way of calculating the odds that checking 1.7 million combinations (e.g. actually use combinatorics in the way they are meant to be used).

Comment: You probably don't need to calculate every possible hand but just a general "class" (e.g. full house, 2 of a kind etc.) from what's already known and add up the probabilities (some more info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability). Example: if a player already has 2 equal cards that would rule out flushes, straights and "no pair", so you should be able to calculate the probabilities for each of the other classes and do the same for the other players. Then compare those in an appropriate way (I lack the math atm).